# Cannot build APR-util 1.5.4 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k

Tags: linux, apache, gcc, openssl, apr

I'm trying to build APR-util 1.5.6 for Apache 2.2.32.

I first build OpenSSL 1.0.2k using the following steps:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make
make test
make install
```

I then ran these commands:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LIBS=-ldl
```

I attempted to build APR-util using these commands:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-crypto --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl

make
```

Configure completes successfully, but make fails with the following error:

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pthread      -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -release 1 -module -rpath /usr/local/apr/lib/apr-util-1 -o crypto/apr_crypto_openssl.la crypto/apr_crypto_openssl.lo -L/usr/local/ssl/lib  -lssl -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(mem.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [crypto/apr_crypto_openssl.la] Error 1
```

Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you haven't make `make clean` or `make distclean`.

Answer (score 1):

> I first build OpenSSL 1.0.2k using the following steps:
>
> ```
> ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
> make
> make test
> make install
> ```

You are *not* building a shared object at this step, so the objects are missing relocation data. It eventually leads to:

> ```
> /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(mem.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S
> ```

Configure like the following should clear the issue.

***with Shared Object***

```
./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl\
```

In this configuration, OpenSSL will build the shared object. It will enable the `-fPIC` flag for you.

***without Shared Object***

```
./config -fPIC --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
```

In this configuration, you are not building the shared object. You must enable the `-fPIC` flag.

---

There are other OpenSSL configuration flags you should consider, like `no-ssl2`, `no-ssl3` and `no-comp`. If you are working on a 64-bit Intel machine, then you should also use `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`. Also see [Compilation and Installation | Options](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Earlier you suggested using: "--openssldir=/usr/local/ssl\"  What is the significance of the "\" character at the end?